# Повторяющиеся значения в ComboBox

Tags: c++builder, ado, access, c++

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться с такой проблемой.

Мне нужно в Items ComboBox-а занести значения столбца "**Марка**" из базы Access таблицы "**Auto**", игнорируя повторяющиеся. Использую **TADOConnection**, **TADOTable**, **TDataSource**.

Нашел подобный код на DELFI, переписать под С++ что-то не получилось. Заранее спасибо.

Код добавления значений из БД в ComboBox

```
Form1->Auto->First();
while (!Form1->Auto->Eof)
{
    ComboBox1->Items->Add(Form1->Auto->FieldByName("Марка")->AsString);
    Form1->Auto->Next();
}
```

Comment: А вот как проигноривать повторяющиеся, не знаю. Пробовал IF для сравнения 

    ComboBox1->Items[i]==Auto->FieldByName("Марка")->AsString    

Выдает ошибку: что-то связоное с Items[i]

Comment: Не пробовали пользовать TDBComboBox?

Comment: Это вопрос на форум фриланс :-)

Comment: TDBComboBox проблему не решит.
Если использовать TDBComboBox он выводит все значения из базы, тоесть если етсть в базе повторающиеся то и в TDBComboBox они тоже будут

Answer (score 1, accepted):

исходя что у Вас БД Access, можно следующее:

1. делаешь запрос в БД - так как пишу быстро не проверяя то могу и ошибится:

   ```
   select dictinct Marka, ID from Auto
   ```
2. в Билдере добавляешь на форму связку TADOConnection->TADOQuery(связанную с запросом из БД Аксесс) либо TADODataSet->TDataSource->TDBComboBox

Comment: и кстати в заметке
ComboBox1->Items[i]==Auto->FieldByName("Марка")->AsString
идет сравнение елемента из списка а не значение...
хотя... сорри давно не кодил под VCL

Comment: Спасиба за ответ. Я решил свою проблему.

Comment: каким образом решил?

Comment: А решил таким способом:   

 Form1->Auto->First();
 while (!Form1->Auto->Eof)
  {
   if (ComboBox1->Items->IndexOf(Form1->Auto->FieldByName("Марка")->AsString)==-1)
    {ComboBox1->Items->Add(Form1->Auto->FieldByName("Марка")->AsString);}
   Form1->Auto->Next();
  }